# DrawerLayout onDrawerClosed() calling twice

Tags: java, android, listener, android-view, drawerlayout

I am using the menu drawer as a checklist and onDrawerClosed depending on a int value will charge the user or not to save changes. However the onDrawerClosed method is calling twice, once with the int and the correct value and once with the int and a value of 0? This leads to my program calling both the if and else statements so their changes save and they are prompted to pay.

```
//Used so that when drawer closed banned list saves
public void drawerListener(){
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            customAdaptor.clearJustChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            System.out.println("Cost of Changes:" + customAdaptor.getUserCostOfChange());
            if (customAdaptor.getUserCostOfChange() > 0) {
                getBuyAlert(customAdaptor.getUserCostOfChange());
                customAdaptor.setUserCostOfChange(0);
            }
            else {
                bannedList = customAdaptor.getBannedList();
                databaseReference.child("BannedApps").setValue(bannedList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        }
    });}


Output:
10-26 01:30:40.346 23822-23822/com.shuffle.v01 I/System.out: Cost of 
Changes:1000

10-26 01:30:40.450 23822-23822/com.shuffle.v01 I/System.out: Cost of 
Changes:0
```

Comment: Where from are you calling `drawerListener()` method?

Comment: That's it! God such a stupid error sorry for wasting your time. Had it in onStart instead of onCreate without realising

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `addDrawerListener()` exactly once, because it "**add**"s a listener, **not** "set"s.

That being said, make sure you are calling that code from `onCreate()` of activity (or similar callback of `Fragment`). Otherwise, if you perform it, say, from `onStart()` or `onResume()`, then you are going to add a new listener each time those callbacks are being invoked.